# Migrating SSRS from SQL Server 2012 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a requirement of migrating my whole SQL Server from SQL Server 2012 to 2016. I have already migrated the database engine part. I have not really worked on SSRS (the reporting part), so I need some assistance there.

I will be taking the following steps:

1. I have to backup and restore the ReportServer database and ReportServerTempDB
2. I have to backup and restore the encryption keys
3. I will configure SSRS through Reporting Server Configuration Manager

What else should I do to run the reports here on SQL 2016 the same as on SQL 2012? I have heard we have to manually copy some RDL files to new server, etc.

Comment: If you move the databases then you don't need to move the RDL files (they are contained in the database).  But you do have the essential steps in place.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/migrate-a-reporting-services-installation-native-mode?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @JonathanFite thanks! Meaning the steps which I will perform are enough, and reports would be visible on new SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 3):

**Try RSMigrationTool.exe and RSMigrationUI.exe from Microsoft**

Here's  a brief excerpt from the white paper link I included below, together with the migration tool download URL and Backup/Restore Encryption Key URL:

1. Download the tool at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29560.
2. Extract the files from the MigrationToo.zip file. You need the following two executable programs in the extracted files.
   RSMigrationTool.exe: Command line utility that helps in exporting the reporting services artifacts. 
   RSMigrationUI.exe: GUI interface that allows the users to export the reporting services artifacts.
3. Export the SSRS items by using the RSMigrationTool.exe.

   a.  Open a command prompt as an administrator.

   b.  Navigate to the folder that contains the extracted RSMigrationTool.exe.

   c.  Run the tool with the following parameters.

   RSMigrationTool.exe [-n native_report_server_url] –I
   native_report_server_instance [-h] –f
   migration_metadata_files_folder [-p password]

**White Paper**

http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D20E1C5F-72EA-4505-9F26-FEF9550EFD44/MigratingContentBetweenReportServers.docx

**Migration Tool**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29560

**Backup and Restore Encryption Keys**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-back-up-and-restore-encryption-keys?view=sql-server-2017

**Alternately try restoring the SSRS databases**

And, if you want to go that route, you can try to restore the SSRS ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB  databases to the target server. This example shows moving from SQL 2005 to 2008 SSRS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-back-up-and-restore-encryption-keys?view=sql-server-2017

As always, try all these things on a test/dev SQL Server first.